# Using @supports selector in my less file

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to do the following in my less file:

```
@supports (display: grid) {
  div {
    display: grid;
  }
}
```

But the space between `@supports` and `(display: grid)` says that it's expecting a colon. How can I get around this?

Comment: What Less compiler/version do you use? The reference one handles this code [just fine](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40supports%20(display%3A%20grid)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20div%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20display%3A%20grid%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using visual studio for that ? apparently the problem comes from there, compile the .less file with command line, not VS